# How to get/set 'loved' state in MPMediaItem?

Tags: ios, swift

How to get or set 'loved' state in MPMediaItem? I did a lot of searching, but I could not find it.

I tried the following but nothing works:

```
item["loved"]
item["disliked"]
```

ref) https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18829

In [Cesium](http://www.cesium-app.com) app, I can get/set 'loved' state.

Answer (score -1):

That's not made available to us. [These are the properties](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem/general_media_item_property_keys) made known in Apple's documentation. Anything outside of the static keys defined in that article shouldn't be used in a production app. They may have side-effects, change and not work in future versions, or access private APIs that will cause you to fail your review.

Comment: I am aware of the problem. I just want to use it in a development app.